# Determine text similarity through cluster analysis

Tags: text, cluster-analysis, similarity

I am a senior bachelor student in CS and I currently work on my thesis. For this thesis I wrote a program that uses density-based clustering approach. More specifically, OPTICS algorithm. I have an idea of how to use it, but I don't know if it is valid.

I want to use this algorithm for text classification. Texts are points in the set that have to be clustered, so that the resulting hierarchy consists of categories and subcategories of texts. For example, one such set is "Scientific literature", consisting of subsets "Mathematics", "Biology" etc.

I came up with the idea that I can analyze texts for specific words that are encountered in particular text more often than in the whole dataset, also excluding insignificant words like prepositions. Perhaps I can use open source natural language parsers for that purpose, like Stanford parser. After that the program combines these "characteristic words" from each text into one set, and a certain amount of the most frequent words can be taken from this set. That amount becomes the dimentionality for the clustering, and each word's frequency in a particular text is used as a coordinate of a point. Thus we can cluster them.

The question is, is that idea valid or a complete nonsense? Can clustering in general and density-based clustering in particular be used for such classification? Maybe there is some kind of literature that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

### Clustering != classification.

Run the clustering algorithm, and study the results. **Most likely, there will *not* be a cluster "scientific literature" with subjects "mathematics"** - what do you do then?

Also, clusters will only give you *sets*, that is too coarse for similarity search - on the contrary, **you need *first* to solve the similarity problem**, before you can run clustering algorithms such as OPTICS.

The "idea" you described is pretty much what everybody has been trying for years already.

Comment: I know that clustering only gives me sets, it will be necessary to label these sets manually. What I ask is if the method of getting these sets that I suggested above makes any sense.

Comment: And I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "solving the similarity problem"? I have an OPTICS algorithm that works with points, now all I have to do is to turn documents into points (like the way I suggested above), am I wrong?

Comment: Similarity is hard. Turning documents into points is *not* enough to get a good similarity. *Try* it. TF-IDF is standard in IR. But for clustering, you need a way to *quantify* similarity, ranking is not good enough. Just running OPTICS on TF-IDF vectors won't give you very good results.

Comment: Hm, I assume you mean this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_measure
Okay, I'll read about it. I already found something that may help, but can you recommend any particular information sources?
This project is my own initiative, we didn't really study Data Mining on a bachelor level, so I apologize if my questions seem silly.

Comment: Also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf but let me warn you again that this works well for finding the 10 best matches, but it does not appear to work half as good for clustering. I think you can just try this with ELKI. It has OPTICS as well as cosine and TF-IDF.

Comment: Well, I finally did test OPTICS with TF-IDF. This article was particularly helpful: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.332.4480&rep=rep1&type=pdf
It claims that euclidean distance can be used for texts after all. It has the worst performance, but it does work nevertheless. And my implementation also got some results that are not wrong - texts are indeed similar.